# AWS Redshift: delete hangs while the "and not true" clause appeared

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I executed a sql of delete on aws-redshift, it has been executing for hours but still not finished.

I tried to `VACUUM` the table to 100 percent sorted, but it does not make sense.

The bad sql is :

```
delete from tmp_table
    using my_table
    where (my_table.id = tmp_table.id)
    and (not true);
```

and I swapped these two tables, it still hung.

```
delete from my_table
    using tmp_table
    where (my_table.id = tmp_table.id)
    and (not true);
```

I even swapped the position of conditions and replaced `not true` by `false`, not work.

Finally, I found this sql also hangs:

```
delete from tmp_table using my_table where false;
```

And I executed some other sqls, they ran very fast:

```
select count(*) from tmp_table
join my_table
     on (my_table.id = tmp_table.id)
     and (not true);
```

```
delete from my_table
 using tmp_table
     where (my_table.id = tmp_table.id)
     and (true);
```

I know that I do not need to execute that delete sql cause the condition is always false and it deletes nothing. I just want to know what will lead to the sql hung.

Comment: How many rows are you deleted?  Deletion can be quite expensive, particularly in a columnar database.

Comment: Often a better approach to deletes on Redshift is to select the rows you *do* want into a new table, drop or rename the original table then rename the new table using the original name i.e. replace it. Don't forget, once you do a significant amount of deletes on Redshift you also then need to VACUUM the table as well.

Answer (score 1):

When a SQL "hangs" on any database, 99% of the time it does because of some other process has a lock on the object.

In your case since you were experimenting you probably ran the same statements multiple times and the table you were trying to delete from had a lock.

In order to list the locks in Redshift you can use this query

```
SELECT 
  current_time, 
  c.relname, 
  l.database, 
  l.transaction, 
  l.pid, 
  a.usename, 
  l.mode, 
  l.granted
FROM pg_locks l 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class c ON c.oid = l.relation
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity a ON a.procpid = l.pid
WHERE l.pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

When you identify which process locks the table and after making sure it's ok to kill it, you can do so to remove the bottleneck.

```
select pg_cancel_backend(<pid of the process from above query>)
```

Comment: In that case based on the volume of data you are deleting, it might be faster to create a new table, I have explained how to in my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065014/how-to-speed-up-update-query-on-massive-table/57065083#57065083

Answer (score 0):

you can form like this

```
delete from my_table
where id in (
    select id from tmp_table
    )
```